# how to parse a string to return only numbers meeting certain criteria in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, insert

I am trying to locate numbers within views where the text of the view is in a long format.  I have already been able to convert the `long` to a `char`.

I have been messing around with `replace` and `instr` functions but haven't been able to get it out neatly.

Ideally I would like to populate a table with the following information.

the user (grantee) of the view, the ID values that are in the file, 1 row for each ID.

A sample view would be something like this.

```
Select column1, column2, column3 from table_with_data where ID in (1,5,322,54,12)
```

or

```
Select column1, column2, column3 from table_with_data where ID = 2
```

How could I create 5 rows in a table just pulling the numeric values here in the first case and just 1 for the second?

Comment: can you elaborate it more by putting some sample data with the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

This might get you going:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData (userName, viewString) AS SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 'auser', 'Select column1, column2, column3 from table_with_data where ID in (1,5,322,54,12)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'buser', 'Select column1, column2, column3 from table_with_data where ID in (15,3,22,5,412)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'cuser', 'Select column1, column2, column3 from table_with_data where ID = 2 ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'duser', 'Select column1, column2, column3 from table_with_data where ID = 45' FROM DUAL
);

WITH
MultipleValues (userName, ids) AS (
  SELECT /* MATERIALIZE */
    userName
    , ',' || SUBSTR(viewString, INSTR(viewString, '(') + 1, LENGTH(viewString) - INSTR(viewString, '(') - 1) || ', '
  FROM SampleData
  WHERE INSTR(viewString, '(') > 1
)
SELECT
  userName
  , TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ids, INSTR(ids, ',', 1, lvl) + 1, INSTR(ids, ',', 1, lvl + 1) - INSTR(ids, ',', 1, lvl) - 1)) id
FROM
  (SELECT userName, ids FROM MultipleValues),
  (SELECT LEVEL AS lvl FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100)
WHERE lvl <= LENGTH(ids) - LENGTH(REPLACE(ids, ',')) - 1
UNION ALL
SELECT /* MATERIALIZE */
  userName
  , TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRIM(viewString), '(\d+)$'))
FROM SampleData
WHERE INSTR(viewString, '=') > 1
ORDER BY userName, id;
```

See it running: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d15600/3/0)

Please comment, or extend your question if this needs further detail / adjustment.

Comment: This is similar to what I ended up doing, basically having the instr in the regexp_replace statement to tell it where to start, after the FROM in my case   SELECT regexp_replace(substr(replace(replace(UPPER(v.view_source_v),chr(10)),chr(13)),instr(replace(replace(UPPER(v.view_source_v),chr(10)),chr(13)),'FROM',1)),'[A-Za-z\\r\\n\\_\\.()= ]')    This gives me only DIGITS and commas in my case at least

Comment: You seem to end up with two rows from your input - didn't you want five instead?

Comment: `REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRIM(viewString), '([0-9,]+)\)?$', 1, 1, '', 1)` seems to return the same as your expression (at least as long as there are no line breaks following the ids). See updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/20e68/1/2).

Answer (score 0):

You can try inserting into view, which will act as check option for insert statement

Lets say table has four column like below

```
CREATE TABLE table_with_data 
(ID NUMBER,column1 VARCHAR2(100), column2 VARCHAR2(100), column3 VARCHAR2(100));
```

and view as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SAMP_VIEW
AS
Select * from table_with_data where ID = 2
```

After creation we can try inserting into view as below

```
INSERT INTO SAMP_VIEW values(2,'hello','hello','hello');
```

if you try insert other than `id = 2` then it will throw

```
ORA-01402: view WITH CHECK OPTION where-clause violation
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: that is an interesting thought but I am thinking this would have even more overhead as I would have to go through some thousands of users and check against all id values for each.    I was hoping there would be a way with using either the replace or instr or combinations to remove alpha characters and other non numerical characters but leave the commas, then seperate out the values from there.